# error " cannot convert node to node* " in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

I am trying to write a function for performing BFS in C++. I have used an array of node type(node of the tree) for my queue. I am getting 3 errors saying "cannot convert node to node*" and vica-versa. Can someone please explain how to correct this and also when to use node * and when to use node while using pointers. I am attachingmy code for levelorder and the queue implementation

```
//bfs function
void levelorder(node *r)
{
if(r==NULL)
return;

else
{
    if(r->lcl!=NULL)
    enqueue(r->lcl);
    if(r->rcl!=NULL)
    enqueue(r->rcl);

    cout<<r->n<<"   ";

    node *k=dequeue();
    levelorder(k);

}
}

int h=-1,t=-1; //head and tail for queue
//node structure 
struct node{
int n;
node *rcl;
node *lcl;
} b[15];       //b is the queue

void enqueue(node i)
{
if(h==-1)
{
    h++;
    t++;
    b[h]=i;
}

else if(t==49)
{
    cout<<"FULL"<<endl;
}

else
{
    t++;
    b[t]=i;
}
}

node *dequeue()
{
if(h==-1)
{
cout<<"EMPTY ";
return NULL;
}

else
{
    return b[h++];
}

}
```

Comment: Both your question and code is unclear and doesn't exactly point to the problem at hand. Please edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

> "cannot convert node to node*" and vica-versa.

convert from node to node*

```
node n;   // auto var node

node* nP = &n;   // a pointer to that node
```

convert from node* to node

```
node* nP = new node;

node  n2 = *nP;   // copy the node into n2
```

or use nP directly by derefencing it

```
foo(node* nP) {
   std::cout << nP->right << std::endl;
}
```

or create a reference from a non-null pointer

```
node& nR = *np;
```

When use one or the other?

I use them interchangeably ... but biased by size, a pointer (node*) is smaller than a (node).